# Realm migration inadequately documented. Can anyone clarify?

Tags: ios, realm

Performing migrations on a Realm database is poorly documented and the documentation seems to be out-of-date. There are two areas explaining how to migrate data:

-- The simple example on the Realm website:  https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

-- A more detailed example in the Github examples section:  https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-3.0/Migration/AppDelegate.swift

Neither of these examples adequately explain how to migrate data between schema versions. I've tried playing around with the examples and have yet to get any migrations working. As well, I've had problems with app crashes when upgrading to newer Realm versions without schema changes and data changes, which don't occur in the Simulator but occur when installing the app from TestFlight or the App Store.

Seems like the Realm documentation and examples detailing migrations are due for a refresh. My areas of interest are:

1. Upgrading to a newer Realm version without a schema change in the database. Unclear whether I should continue using the default.realm file generated with a previous version, or whether I need to re-generate the default.realm file using the newer Realm framework version.
2. Adding a new attribute to a Realm object.
3. New objects ("rows") added to an existing class without any schema change.
4. No schema changes to existing classes in the database, but addition of an entirely new class or classes.
5. Any combination of the above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Sorry the docs are not sufficient. We appreciate the feedback and will use it to improve them. In the mean time, let me answer your questions:

1. You do not need to do anything when you upgrade the SDK. Sometimes, we upgrade the core database file format, but this migration happens automatically when you open the Realm (`Realm()`) so you don't have to worry about it.
2. When you add a new property to an object you can just follow this code snippet.

*Nothing is needed in the migration block since this block is simply to apply data transformations between versions. All you need to do is increment the `schemaVersion`*

```
// Inside your application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

let config = Realm.Configuration(
  // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
  // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
  schemaVersion: 1,

  // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
  // a schema version lower than the one set above
  migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
    // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
      // Nothing to do!
      // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
      // And will update the schema on disk automatically
    }
  })

// Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

// Now that we've told Realm how to handle the schema change, opening the file
// will automatically perform the migration
let realm = try! Realm()
```

3. Adding objects to a Realm does not affect the schema so a migration is not relevant.
4. This is the same as 2, you simply need to increment the `schemaVersion` but you don't have to do anything in the migration block since Realm handles everything. The migration block is for custom migration logic where, for example, you want to transform `firstName` and `lastName` from `schemaVersion=0` to `fullName` when updating to `schemaVersion=1`. In this case, you could get the data from the old version and concatenate the strings into the new `fullName` property within the migration block.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that doesn't work, at all. There is a block of code I had to add to iOS apps several months ago in order to get Realm to work, but it doesn't solve the migration problems I've experienced:

```
      config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("default-v1.realm")
  Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

  // copy over old data files for migration
  //let defaultURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
  let defaultURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
  //print("Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL! = \(defaultURL)")
  //let defaultParentURL = defaultURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent

  if let realmURL = bundleURL("default-v1") {
    do {
      //print("Bundle location for default.realm = \(realmURL)")
      let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
      let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
      let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent("default-v1.realm").path
      let fileManager = FileManager.default
      if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {

         print("FILE INSTALLED")
        print("Documents location for default.realm = \(filePath)")
      } else {
        //print("FILE NOT INSTALLED, COPYING default.realm from bundle to Documents directory.")
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: realmURL, to: defaultURL)
      }
    } catch {}
  }
```

I suspect that a new default-v1.realm file may clobber an existing default-v1.realm file on a user's device, using this code with the "Nothing is needed" migration method.

Part of the confusion stems from the example migration code at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/swift-3.0/Migration where data from the v1 file is getting copied over to the v2 file. Regardless, I've tried the "Nothing is needed" code you've posted and the app doesn't find any Realm data then crashes.

It looks like I could splice the code you've posted into the code I've been using then perhaps that would solve the problem. Will look into that next week.

Thanks for your response!

Comment: I don't understand why you are messing with the Realm files themselves? There appears to be a more general misconception driving your questions, but it's not obvious to me how to clarify it without understanding your codebase further.

Comment: Adrien: you should copy all of this answer and paste it into your original question, after inserting "Edit:" or something similar. This is not an answer, and should be deleted.

Comment: Adam, I'm "messing with them" because if I don't the app crashes.

Comment: Mozahler, it is not possible to add my response in the "Comments" box, it is too long, but it is necessary to include the information as posted. Looks like StackOverflow should extend the functionality of the "Comment" box. Thank you.

Comment: No "general misconception." Thank you for attempting to address the issue. As soon as I can get around to it I will create a very simple app on Github where I can play around with this and at that point I will point you to the problem if I can recreate it in that example app.